# Rstan won't run just stops at prompt "Selection"

Tags: c++, r, rstan

I followed the instructions to install Rstan from [here](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started).  I used the [macrtools](https://github.com/coatless-mac/macrtools) to configure the c++ toolchain. But whenever I run any Rstan program it just stops with the prompt "Selection:"

For example if I run the example as it instructs on the Rstan Github page I get the following output:

```r
example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)                                                                 
Loading required package: StanHeaders
Loading required package: ggplot2
rstan (Version 2.21.8, GitRev: 2e1f913d3ca3)
For execution on a local, multicore CPU with excess RAM we recommend calling
options(mc.cores = parallel::detectCores()).
To avoid recompilation of unchanged Stan programs, we recommend calling
rstan_options(auto_write = TRUE)

stn_mdr$> stancode <- 'data {real y_mean;} parameters {real y;} model {y ~ normal(y_mean,1);}'

stn_mdr$> mod <- stan_model(model_code = stancode, verbose = TRUE)

TRANSLATING MODEL '16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9' FROM Stan CODE TO C++ CODE NOW.
successful in parsing the Stan model '16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9'.
COMPILING THE C++ CODE FOR MODEL '16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9' NOW.
OS: aarch64, darwin20; rstan: 2.21.8; Rcpp: 1.0.10; inline: 0.3.19 
 >> setting environment variables: 
PKG_LIBS =  '/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a' -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb
PKG_CPPFLAGS =   -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/BH/include" -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1 
 >> Program source :

   1 : 
   2 : // includes from the plugin
   3 : // [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp14)]]
   4 : 
   5 : 
   6 : // user includes
   7 : #include <Rcpp.h>
   8 : #include <rstan/io/rlist_ref_var_context.hpp>
   9 : #include <rstan/io/r_ostream.hpp>
  10 : #include <rstan/stan_args.hpp>
  11 : #include <boost/integer/integer_log2.hpp>
  12 : // Code generated by Stan version 2.21.0
  13 : 
  14 : #include <stan/model/model_header.hpp>
  15 : 
  16 : namespace model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9_namespace {
  17 : 
  18 : using std::istream;
  19 : using std::string;
  20 : using std::stringstream;
  21 : using std::vector;
  22 : using stan::io::dump;
  23 : using stan::math::lgamma;
  24 : using stan::model::prob_grad;
  25 : using namespace stan::math;
  26 : 
  27 : static int current_statement_begin__;
  28 : 
  29 : stan::io::program_reader prog_reader__() {
  30 :     stan::io::program_reader reader;
  31 :     reader.add_event(0, 0, "start", "model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9");
  32 :     reader.add_event(3, 1, "end", "model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9");
  33 :     return reader;
  34 : }
  35 : 
  36 : class model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9
  37 :   : public stan::model::model_base_crtp<model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9> {
  38 : private:
  39 :         double y_mean;
  40 : public:
  41 :     model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9(rstan::io::rlist_ref_var_context& context__,
  42 :         std::ostream* pstream__ = 0)
  43 :         : model_base_crtp(0) {
  44 :         ctor_body(context__, 0, pstream__);
  45 :     }
  46 : 
  47 :     model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9(stan::io::var_context& context__,
  48 :         unsigned int random_seed__,
  49 :         std::ostream* pstream__ = 0)
  50 :         : model_base_crtp(0) {
  51 :         ctor_body(context__, random_seed__, pstream__);
  52 :     }
  53 : 
  54 :     void ctor_body(stan::io::var_context& context__,
  55 :                    unsigned int random_seed__,
  56 :                    std::ostream* pstream__) {
  57 :         typedef double local_scalar_t__;
  58 : 
  59 :         boost::ecuyer1988 base_rng__ =
  60 :           stan::services::util::create_rng(random_seed__, 0);
  61 :         (void) base_rng__;  // suppress unused var warning
  62 : 
  63 :         current_statement_begin__ = -1;
  64 : 
  65 :         static const char* function__ = "model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9_namespace::model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9";
  66 :         (void) function__;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
  67 :         size_t pos__;
  68 :         (void) pos__;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
  69 :         std::vector<int> vals_i__;
  70 :         std::vector<double> vals_r__;
  71 :         local_scalar_t__ DUMMY_VAR__(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
  72 :         (void) DUMMY_VAR__;  // suppress unused var warning
  73 : 
  74 :         try {
  75 :             // initialize data block variables from context__
  76 :             current_statement_begin__ = 1;
  77 :             context__.validate_dims("data initialization", "y_mean", "double", context__.to_vec());
  78 :             y_mean = double(0);
  79 :             vals_r__ = context__.vals_r("y_mean");
  80 :             pos__ = 0;
  81 :             y_mean = vals_r__[pos__++];
  82 : 
  83 : 
  84 :             // initialize transformed data variables
  85 :             // execute transformed data statements
  86 : 
  87 :             // validate transformed data
  88 : 
  89 :             // validate, set parameter ranges
  90 :             num_params_r__ = 0U;
  91 :             param_ranges_i__.clear();
  92 :             current_statement_begin__ = 1;
  93 :             num_params_r__ += 1;
  94 :         } catch (const std::exception& e) {
  95 :             stan::lang::rethrow_located(e, current_statement_begin__, prog_reader__());
  96 :             // Next line prevents compiler griping about no return
  97 :             throw std::runtime_error("*** IF YOU SEE THIS, PLEASE REPORT A BUG ***");
  98 :         }
  99 :     }
 100 : 
 101 :     ~model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9() { }
 102 : 
 103 : 
 104 :     void transform_inits(const stan::io::var_context& context__,
 105 :                          std::vector<int>& params_i__,
 106 :                          std::vector<double>& params_r__,
 107 :                          std::ostream* pstream__) const {
 108 :         typedef double local_scalar_t__;
 109 :         stan::io::writer<double> writer__(params_r__, params_i__);
 110 :         size_t pos__;
 111 :         (void) pos__; // dummy call to supress warning
 112 :         std::vector<double> vals_r__;
 113 :         std::vector<int> vals_i__;
 114 : 
 115 :         current_statement_begin__ = 1;
 116 :         if (!(context__.contains_r("y")))
 117 :             stan::lang::rethrow_located(std::runtime_error(std::string("Variable y missing")), current_statement_begin__, prog_reader__());
 118 :         vals_r__ = context__.vals_r("y");
 119 :         pos__ = 0U;
 120 :         context__.validate_dims("parameter initialization", "y", "double", context__.to_vec());
 121 :         double y(0);
 122 :         y = vals_r__[pos__++];
 123 :         try {
 124 :             writer__.scalar_unconstrain(y);
 125 :         } catch (const std::exception& e) {
 126 :             stan::lang::rethrow_located(std::runtime_error(std::string("Error transforming variable y: ") + e.what()), current_statement_begin__, prog_reader__());
 127 :         }
 128 : 
 129 :         params_r__ = writer__.data_r();
 130 :         params_i__ = writer__.data_i();
 131 :     }
 132 : 
 133 :     void transform_inits(const stan::io::var_context& context,
 134 :                          Eigen::Matrix<double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1>& params_r,
 135 :                          std::ostream* pstream__) const {
 136 :       std::vector<double> params_r_vec;
 137 :       std::vector<int> params_i_vec;
 138 :       transform_inits(context, params_i_vec, params_r_vec, pstream__);
 139 :       params_r.resize(params_r_vec.size());
 140 :       for (int i = 0; i < params_r.size(); ++i)
 141 :         params_r(i) = params_r_vec[i];
 142 :     }
 143 : 
 144 : 
 145 :     template <bool propto__, bool jacobian__, typename T__>
 146 :     T__ log_prob(std::vector<T__>& params_r__,
 147 :                  std::vector<int>& params_i__,
 148 :                  std::ostream* pstream__ = 0) const {
 149 : 
 150 :         typedef T__ local_scalar_t__;
 151 : 
 152 :         local_scalar_t__ DUMMY_VAR__(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
 153 :         (void) DUMMY_VAR__;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
 154 : 
 155 :         T__ lp__(0.0);
 156 :         stan::math::accumulator<T__> lp_accum__;
 157 :         try {
 158 :             stan::io::reader<local_scalar_t__> in__(params_r__, params_i__);
 159 : 
 160 :             // model parameters
 161 :             current_statement_begin__ = 1;
 162 :             local_scalar_t__ y;
 163 :             (void) y;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
 164 :             if (jacobian__)
 165 :                 y = in__.scalar_constrain(lp__);
 166 :             else
 167 :                 y = in__.scalar_constrain();
 168 : 
 169 :             // model body
 170 : 
 171 :             current_statement_begin__ = 1;
 172 :             lp_accum__.add(normal_log<propto__>(y, y_mean, 1));
 173 : 
 174 :         } catch (const std::exception& e) {
 175 :             stan::lang::rethrow_located(e, current_statement_begin__, prog_reader__());
 176 :             // Next line prevents compiler griping about no return
 177 :             throw std::runtime_error("*** IF YOU SEE THIS, PLEASE REPORT A BUG ***");
 178 :         }
 179 : 
 180 :         lp_accum__.add(lp__);
 181 :         return lp_accum__.sum();
 182 : 
 183 :     } // log_prob()
 184 : 
 185 :     template <bool propto, bool jacobian, typename T_>
 186 :     T_ log_prob(Eigen::Matrix<T_,Eigen::Dynamic,1>& params_r,
 187 :                std::ostream* pstream = 0) const {
 188 :       std::vector<T_> vec_params_r;
 189 :       vec_params_r.reserve(params_r.size());
 190 :       for (int i = 0; i < params_r.size(); ++i)
 191 :         vec_params_r.push_back(params_r(i));
 192 :       std::vector<int> vec_params_i;
 193 :       return log_prob<propto,jacobian,T_>(vec_params_r, vec_params_i, pstream);
 194 :     }
 195 : 
 196 : 
 197 :     void get_param_names(std::vector<std::string>& names__) const {
 198 :         names__.resize(0);
 199 :         names__.push_back("y");
 200 :     }
 201 : 
 202 : 
 203 :     void get_dims(std::vector<std::vector<size_t> >& dimss__) const {
 204 :         dimss__.resize(0);
 205 :         std::vector<size_t> dims__;
 206 :         dims__.resize(0);
 207 :         dimss__.push_back(dims__);
 208 :     }
 209 : 
 210 :     template <typename RNG>
 211 :     void write_array(RNG& base_rng__,
 212 :                      std::vector<double>& params_r__,
 213 :                      std::vector<int>& params_i__,
 214 :                      std::vector<double>& vars__,
 215 :                      bool include_tparams__ = true,
 216 :                      bool include_gqs__ = true,
 217 :                      std::ostream* pstream__ = 0) const {
 218 :         typedef double local_scalar_t__;
 219 : 
 220 :         vars__.resize(0);
 221 :         stan::io::reader<local_scalar_t__> in__(params_r__, params_i__);
 222 :         static const char* function__ = "model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9_namespace::write_array";
 223 :         (void) function__;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
 224 : 
 225 :         // read-transform, write parameters
 226 :         double y = in__.scalar_constrain();
 227 :         vars__.push_back(y);
 228 : 
 229 :         double lp__ = 0.0;
 230 :         (void) lp__;  // dummy to suppress unused var warning
 231 :         stan::math::accumulator<double> lp_accum__;
 232 : 
 233 :         local_scalar_t__ DUMMY_VAR__(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
 234 :         (void) DUMMY_VAR__;  // suppress unused var warning
 235 : 
 236 :         if (!include_tparams__ && !include_gqs__) return;
 237 : 
 238 :         try {
 239 :             if (!include_gqs__ && !include_tparams__) return;
 240 :             if (!include_gqs__) return;
 241 :         } catch (const std::exception& e) {
 242 :             stan::lang::rethrow_located(e, current_statement_begin__, prog_reader__());
 243 :             // Next line prevents compiler griping about no return
 244 :             throw std::runtime_error("*** IF YOU SEE THIS, PLEASE REPORT A BUG ***");
 245 :         }
 246 :     }
 247 : 
 248 :     template <typename RNG>
 249 :     void write_array(RNG& base_rng,
 250 :                      Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1>& params_r,
 251 :                      Eigen::Matrix<double,Eigen::Dynamic,1>& vars,
 252 :                      bool include_tparams = true,
 253 :                      bool include_gqs = true,
 254 :                      std::ostream* pstream = 0) const {
 255 :       std::vector<double> params_r_vec(params_r.size());
 256 :       for (int i = 0; i < params_r.size(); ++i)
 257 :         params_r_vec[i] = params_r(i);
 258 :       std::vector<double> vars_vec;
 259 :       std::vector<int> params_i_vec;
 260 :       write_array(base_rng, params_r_vec, params_i_vec, vars_vec, include_tparams, include_gqs, pstream);
 261 :       vars.resize(vars_vec.size());
 262 :       for (int i = 0; i < vars.size(); ++i)
 263 :         vars(i) = vars_vec[i];
 264 :     }
 265 : 
 266 :     std::string model_name() const {
 267 :         return "model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9";
 268 :     }
 269 : 
 270 : 
 271 :     void constrained_param_names(std::vector<std::string>& param_names__,
 272 :                                  bool include_tparams__ = true,
 273 :                                  bool include_gqs__ = true) const {
 274 :         std::stringstream param_name_stream__;
 275 :         param_name_stream__.str(std::string());
 276 :         param_name_stream__ << "y";
 277 :         param_names__.push_back(param_name_stream__.str());
 278 : 
 279 :         if (!include_gqs__ && !include_tparams__) return;
 280 : 
 281 :         if (include_tparams__) {
 282 :         }
 283 : 
 284 :         if (!include_gqs__) return;
 285 :     }
 286 : 
 287 : 
 288 :     void unconstrained_param_names(std::vector<std::string>& param_names__,
 289 :                                    bool include_tparams__ = true,
 290 :                                    bool include_gqs__ = true) const {
 291 :         std::stringstream param_name_stream__;
 292 :         param_name_stream__.str(std::string());
 293 :         param_name_stream__ << "y";
 294 :         param_names__.push_back(param_name_stream__.str());
 295 : 
 296 :         if (!include_gqs__ && !include_tparams__) return;
 297 : 
 298 :         if (include_tparams__) {
 299 :         }
 300 : 
 301 :         if (!include_gqs__) return;
 302 :     }
 303 : 
 304 : }; // model
 305 : 
 306 : }  // namespace
 307 : 
 308 : typedef model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9_namespace::model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9 stan_model;
 309 : 
 310 : #ifndef USING_R
 311 : 
 312 : stan::model::model_base& new_model(
 313 :         stan::io::var_context& data_context,
 314 :         unsigned int seed,
 315 :         std::ostream* msg_stream) {
 316 :   stan_model* m = new stan_model(data_context, seed, msg_stream);
 317 :   return *m;
 318 : }
 319 : 
 320 : #endif
 321 : 
 322 : 
 323 : 
 324 : #include <rstan_next/stan_fit.hpp>
 325 : 
 326 : struct stan_model_holder {
 327 :     stan_model_holder(rstan::io::rlist_ref_var_context rcontext,
 328 :                       unsigned int random_seed)
 329 :     : rcontext_(rcontext), random_seed_(random_seed)
 330 :      {
 331 :      }
 332 : 
 333 :    //stan::math::ChainableStack ad_stack;
 334 :    rstan::io::rlist_ref_var_context rcontext_;
 335 :    unsigned int random_seed_;
 336 : };
 337 : 
 338 : Rcpp::XPtr<stan::model::model_base> model_ptr(stan_model_holder* smh) {
 339 :   Rcpp::XPtr<stan::model::model_base> model_instance(new stan_model(smh->rcontext_, smh->random_seed_), true);
 340 :   return model_instance;
 341 : }
 342 : 
 343 : Rcpp::XPtr<rstan::stan_fit_base> fit_ptr(stan_model_holder* smh) {
 344 :   return Rcpp::XPtr<rstan::stan_fit_base>(new rstan::stan_fit(model_ptr(smh), smh->random_seed_), true);
 345 : }
 346 : 
 347 : std::string model_name(stan_model_holder* smh) {
 348 :   return model_ptr(smh).get()->model_name();
 349 : }
 350 : 
 351 : RCPP_MODULE(stan_fit4model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9_mod){
 352 :   Rcpp::class_<stan_model_holder>("stan_fit4model12da37b67101_16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9")
 353 :   .constructor<rstan::io::rlist_ref_var_context, unsigned int>()
 354 :   .method("model_ptr", &model_ptr)
 355 :   .method("fit_ptr", &fit_ptr)
 356 :   .method("model_name", &model_name)
 357 :   ;
 358 : }
 359 : 
 360 : 
 361 : // declarations
 362 : extern "C" {
 363 : SEXP file12da30fc0747( ) ;
 364 : }
 365 : 
 366 : // definition
 367 : SEXP file12da30fc0747() {
 368 :  return Rcpp::wrap("16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9");
 369 : }
make cmd is
  make -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/etc/Makeconf' -f '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/share/make/shlib.mk' -f '/Users/michaelschmidt/.R/Makevars' CXX='$(CXX14) $(CXX14STD)' CXXFLAGS='$(CXX14FLAGS)' CXXPICFLAGS='$(CXX14PICFLAGS)' SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXX14LDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXX14LD)' SHLIB='file12da30fc0747.so' OBJECTS='file12da30fc0747.o'

make would use
clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/Rcpp/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppEigen/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppEigen/include/unsupported"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/BH/include" -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/src/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppParallel/include/"  -I"/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan/include" -DEIGEN_NO_DEBUG  -DBOOST_DISABLE_ASSERTS  -DBOOST_PENDING_INTEGER_LOG2_HPP  -DSTAN_THREADS  -DBOOST_NO_AUTO_PTR  -include '/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/include/stan/math/prim/fun/Eigen.hpp'  -D_REENTRANT -DRCPP_PARALLEL_USE_TBB=1   -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -O3 -mtune=native -arch arm64 -ftemplate-depth-256 -c file12da30fc0747.cpp -o file12da30fc0747.o
if test  "zfile12da30fc0747.o" != "z"; then \
          echo clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib" -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o file12da30fc0747.so file12da30fc0747.o  '/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a' -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64 -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation; \
          clang++ -arch arm64 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/lib" -L/opt/R/arm64/lib -o file12da30fc0747.so file12da30fc0747.o  '/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan/lib//libStanServices.a' -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/StanHeaders/lib/' -lStanHeaders -L'/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/RcppParallel/lib/' -ltbb  -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64 -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation; \
        fi

stn_mdr$> fit <- sampling(mod, data = list(y_mean = 0))

SAMPLING FOR MODEL '16a540c6086086816528e4524def24d9' NOW (CHAIN 1).
Selection:
```

And it just stops.  If I run any rstan program I get the same.  I have no idea what is going on.  Here is my session info:

```r
r$> devtools::session_info("rstan")                                                                                            
─ Session info ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.0 (2023-04-21)
 os       macOS Ventura 13.3.1
 system   aarch64, darwin20
 ui       X11
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/Denver
 date     2023-06-13
 pandoc   3.1.2 @ /opt/homebrew/bin/pandoc

─ Packages ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package      * version   date (UTC) lib source
 backports      1.4.1     2021-12-13 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 BH             1.81.0-1  2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 callr          3.7.3     2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 checkmate      2.2.0     2023-04-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 cli            3.6.1     2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 colorspace     2.1-0     2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 crayon         1.5.2     2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 desc           1.4.2     2022-09-08 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fansi          1.0.4     2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 farver         2.1.1     2022-07-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ggplot2        3.4.2     2023-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 glue           1.6.2     2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 gridExtra      2.3       2017-09-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 gtable         0.3.3     2023-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 inline         0.3.19    2021-05-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 isoband        0.2.7     2022-12-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 labeling       0.4.2     2020-10-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 lattice        0.21-8    2023-04-05 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 lifecycle      1.0.3     2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 loo            2.6.0     2023-03-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 magrittr       2.0.3     2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 MASS           7.3-58.4  2023-03-07 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 Matrix         1.5-4     2023-04-04 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 matrixStats    1.0.0     2023-06-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 mgcv           1.8-42    2023-03-02 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 munsell        0.5.0     2018-06-12 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 nlme           3.1-162   2023-01-31 [2] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pillar         1.9.0     2023-03-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgbuild       1.4.0     2022-11-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgconfig      2.0.3     2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 prettyunits    1.1.1     2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 processx       3.8.1     2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ps             1.7.5     2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 R6             2.5.1     2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 RColorBrewer   1.1-3     2022-04-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 Rcpp           1.0.10    2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 RcppEigen      0.3.3.9.3 2022-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 RcppParallel   5.1.7     2023-02-27 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rlang          1.1.0     2023-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rprojroot      2.0.3     2022-04-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rstan          2.21.8    2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 scales         1.2.1     2022-08-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 StanHeaders    2.26.26   2023-05-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 tibble         3.2.1     2023-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 utf8           1.2.3     2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 vctrs          0.6.2     2023-04-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 viridisLite    0.4.1     2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 withr          2.5.0     2022-03-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

 [1] /Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library
 [2] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-arm64/Resources/library

─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

I've only found a single other person experiencing this and they just abandoned Rstan.  But I want to use the BRMS package.  Not sure what to do.

Edit:
Contents of my ~/.R/Makevars file:

```
CXX14FLAGS += -O3 -mtune=native -arch arm64 -ftemplate-depth-256
```

c++ location, g++ location and g++-13 location

```bash
> which -a c++
/usr/bin/c++
> which -a g++
/usr/bin/g++
> which g++-13
g++-13 not found
```

#### Command Installed rstan with

I tried both commands from the [getting started with Rstan page](https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started).

```
## This one
install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)
## and this one
install.packages("rstan", repos = c("https://mc-stan.org/r-packages/", getOption("repos")))
```

### A few other potentially helpful notes

- I'm also using [rig](https://github.com/r-lib/rig).
- And I do have homebrew installed and use it often.

Comment: Perhaps try providing a 'selection', i.e. type "1" and hit "enter". If I run `stan_demo("dogs")` I get the output "Do you want to download the example models?" with three options (1: Download to include directory of the rstan package
2: Download to the temporary directory
3: Do not download") then the prompt says "Selection:", so it's worth a shot

Comment: Thanks jared_marmot. If I provide a selection such as "1" and press enter it crashes R.  The Selection: comes up too when I try making another model and not just the example.

Comment: Thought it was worth a shot, but it's not surprising it didn't fix the issue. Another idea is to try the [cmdstanr interface](https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/) and see if you can get the example to complete successfully. If so, that likely narrows down the problem to your C++ toolchain

Comment: I got cmdstanr up and running and everything seems to be working fine.  Got multiple examples to work in both raw cmdstan from a zsh terminal and cmdstanr working in R. Any pointers on how I would I go about debugging/fixing my c++ toolchain for stanR?

Comment: I have some ideas, but you'll have to do most of the troubleshooting yourself because I can't replicate the problem and I don't have an apple silicon chip (my compiler setup will be different to yours). Some more details might help: can you please edit your question to include the contents of your `~/.R/Makevars` file and the output from the terminal commands `which -a c++`, `which g++`, `which g++-13`. Do you have homebrew installed? What command did you use to install rstan?

Comment: I edited my post above with the answers to your questions.  I do use homebrew.  Is there anything else?  I really really appreciate the help.  Thank you!

Comment: First thing I would suggest is to try the most up-to-date gcc version of 'c++'. You can install gcc via homebrew (`brew install gcc`; takes a long time) then add the lines `CXX=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13`, `CXX14=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/bin/g++-13` and `LDFLAGS+=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/current/` to your `~/.R/Makevars` file and see if the package compiles without error

Comment: I installed gcc with homebrew, then added the lines you recommended above to my , `~/.R/Makevars` file with the modification that the cellar is located at `opt/homebrew/Cellar` on Silicon macs. Now the example just crashes R with a warning that flashes too fast to read, but it says something with invalid argument in it.

Comment: Ahh man, that error code would've been helpful. Does R crash if you remove the `LDFLAGS+=-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/13.1.0/lib/gcc/current/` line from your Makevars and try again?

Comment: It still crashes even if I remove that line from the Makevars file.  And I tried really hard to read the error when it crashes but it flashes way too fast. Thank you so much for trying to help.  I really really appreciate it.

Comment: That's frustrating! Next step: edit your ~/.R/Makevars back to `CXX14FLAGS += -O3 -mtune=native -arch arm64 -ftemplate-depth-256` and try removing rstan and reinstalling the dev version. **In a new session** type `remove.packages("rstan")` then restart R and run `remotes::install_github("stan-dev/rstan", ref = "develop", subdir = "rstan/rstan")` and see if it compiles without error, then try the `library(rstan); example(stan_model, package = "rstan", run.dontrun = TRUE)` example again - hopefully you get a more informative error message (or maybe it'll just work)

Comment: I tried to install rstan after returning my Makevars file removing rstan, restarting R, and downloading rstan dev version.  Got this error at the end: 
`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [rstan.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rstan’
* removing ‘/Users/michaelschmidt/Library/R/arm64/4.3/library/rstan’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/qj/w8fq61fx08g53mypxhcnvffh0000gn/T//RtmpNtc1mm/file3c3863de9115/rstan_2.21.3.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status`

Comment: Did you make any progress with this problem @Mike Schmidt? Based on the error compiling rstan I think the next step is to delete your `~/.R/Makevars` file, or revert it to what you had at the start, and install the binary (`install.packages("rstan", repos = "https://cloud.r-project.org/", dependencies = TRUE)`), then try using cmdstanr as the brm backend, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577274/12957340

Comment: Yes. I just ended up using cmdstanr as a backend. Thank you for all of your help.  I really appreciate it @jared_mamrot.