# rstan/brms cause R and RStudio session abort

Tags: r, rstan, brms

I am experiencing a very similar issue as [rstan and brms cause R and RStudio session abort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72168874/rstan-and-brms-cause-r-and-rstudio-session-abort/76575711#76575711). Whenever it starts sampling, R crashes (R session abort).

I have tried reinstalling `rstan` along the suggested dependencies, but it has not worked.

Would you happen to have any suggestions?

- update 1

```
─ Session info ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
 os       macOS Ventura 13.4.1
 system   x86_64, darwin20
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8
 tz       Europe/London
 date     2023-06-28
 rstudio  2023.03.0+386 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
 pandoc   2.11 @ /Users/edoardogiuseppeostinelli/opt/anaconda3/bin/pandoc

─ Packages ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package     * version date (UTC) lib source
 cachem        1.0.8   2023-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 callr         3.7.3   2022-11-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 cli           3.6.1   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 crayon        1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 devtools      2.4.5   2022-10-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 digest        0.6.32  2023-06-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ellipsis      0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fastmap       1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 fs            1.6.2   2023-04-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 glue          1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 htmltools     0.5.5   2023-03-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 htmlwidgets   1.6.2   2023-03-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 httpuv        1.6.11  2023-05-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 later         1.3.1   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 lifecycle     1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 magrittr      2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 memoise       2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 mime          0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 miniUI        0.1.1.1 2018-05-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgbuild      1.4.2   2023-06-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 pkgload       1.3.2   2022-11-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 prettyunits   1.1.1   2020-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 processx      3.8.1   2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 profvis       0.3.8   2023-05-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 promises      1.2.0.1 2021-02-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 ps            1.7.5   2023-04-18 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 purrr         1.0.1   2023-01-10 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 R6            2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 Rcpp          1.0.10  2023-01-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 remotes       2.4.2   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rlang         1.1.1   2023-04-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 rstudioapi    0.14    2022-08-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 sessioninfo   1.2.2   2021-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 shiny         1.7.4   2022-12-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringi       1.7.12  2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 stringr       1.5.0   2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 urlchecker    1.0.1   2021-11-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 usethis       2.2.1   2023-06-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 vctrs         0.6.3   2023-06-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)
 xtable        1.8-4   2019-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 4.3.0)

 [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library
```

Comment: use `cmdstanr` backend?  Please tell us the versions of everything you're using (RStudio as well as packages: `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` output would be useful)

Comment: How can I use `cmdstanr` backend? I am sorry but I am not that experienced, I am afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `cmdstanr` backend

- First follow the [instructions for installing cmdstanr](https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/articles/cmdstanr.html)
- then see the `backend` argument of `brm()`:

> `backend`: Character string naming the package to use as the backend for
> fitting the Stan model. Options are ‘"rstan"’ (the default)
> or ‘"cmdstanr"’. Can be set globally for the current R
> session via the ‘"brms.backend"’ option (see ‘options’).
> Details on the ‘rstan’ and ‘cmdstanr’ packages are available
> at https://mc-stan.org/rstan/ and
> https://mc-stan.org/cmdstanr/, respectively.

I also have some setup instructions [here](http://bbolker.github.io/bbmisc/bayes/setup.html).

Comment: Many thanks, changing the `backend` argument of `brm()` seems to have fixed the issue.