# Rstan error with Apple M1 chip in Mac OSX Montery/Ventura: "unknown target CPU 'apple-m1'"

Tags: r, macos, clang, apple-m1, rstan

I have been having trouble running rstan on my Macbook Pro since I updated to OSX 12. I have tried updating R, RStudio, rstan, XCode, OSX, and the problem persisted. Initially, the error was something along the line of "march=native not supported". Now with all the updates, the error became

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
      #pragma clang diagnostic pop                             ^18 warnings generated.error: unknown target CPU 'apple-m1'note: valid target CPU values are: nocona, core2, penryn, bonnell, atom, silvermont, slm, goldmont, goldmont-plus, tremont, nehalem, corei7, westmere, sandybridge, corei7-avx, ivybridge, core-avx-i, haswell, core-avx2, broadwell, skylake, skylake-avx512, skx, cascadelake, cooperlake, cannonlake, icelake-client, rocketlake, icelake-server, tigerlake, sapphirerapids, alderlake, knl, knm, k8, athlon64, athlon-fx, opteron, k8-sse3, athlon64-sse3, opteron-sse3, amdfam10, barcelona, btver1, btver2, bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1, znver2, znver3, x86-64, x86-64-v2, x86-64-v3, x86-64-v4make: *** [file32ac3ef1d6.o] Error 1
```

Now, when I typed "clang --print-supported-cpus" into the Terminal, "apple-m1" did show up, so I suspect it's simply a matter of rstan using the wrong versions/options of things for the compilation. I took a look at my /.R/Makevars file, and it says

```
CXX14FLAGS=-O3 -march=native -mtune=native
CXX14FLAGS += -arch x86_64 -ftemplate-depth-256
CPPFLAGS="-isystem /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

I tried messing around with the file, by deleting things, adding "mcpus=apple-m1", and various other ill-informed shenanigans. I got various results including the same error message, crashing rstan (and R), and compiling the model but running into the message "Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection". I feel I'm completely out of my depth at this point, and I could use some help from someone more familiar with C++ and such.

Thanks a ton in advance!

Comment: I recently tried to help another user troubleshoot installing/running rstan on apple M1, but ultimately didn't solve the problem, r.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/76469180/12957340. A potential workaround is to use cmdstanr instead (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76577274/12957340), but if you want to work out the necessary compiler setup etc it's not a 'simple' task

Comment: This is technically off-topic for stackoverflow since you are asking how to install an application rather than help with a programming question. Notice the compiler flags include `-arch x86_64`. Since your computer is based on Apple Silicon (aka, `arm64` or `apple-m1`) that won't work unless you are cross-compiling for a different architecture. Since your Macbook can run x86_64 binaries using an emulation layer the simplest solution is to compile on an older x86_64 Macbook or Macpro system and copy the binary to your new system.

Comment: @jared_mamrot Thanks. I'll give cmdstanr a try.